# ionic local notification doesnt show as banner in foreground and no sound

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, uilocalnotification, ngcordova

I am creating a hybrid app in ionic and want to show a notification when the app is in foreground. Based on research, the best way to do that is via cordova local notifications but though it works perfectly in Android and shows a banner with sound.

On ios, it only puts the notification in the notification try and doesnt make any sound. Can anyone help me out with this?

Here is my code

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.registerPermission(function (granted) {
  console.log('Permission has been granted: ' + granted);
  cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    text: data._raw.message,
    at: alarmTime,
    data: data._raw.additionalData.loan_id
  });
});
```

Comment: On iOS the received notifications that belongs to the foreground app isn't showed in a banner form and maybe that's the reason that you don't see the banner.

Comment: @tx2 any way i can show it in banner form or at least have a sound when it is fired and sent to notification tray?

Comment: Natively you can catch the notifications and then you can do wathever you want like showing a popup or a bar like the native one (it needs to be a custom component anyway), but as you are using ionic I really don't know if there is a way of doing that. Maybe someone with more experience in ionic can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen for the event when the notification is received. From your code you only schedule a notification to be sent but you do not handle receiving the notification.

This is how you register the event when the notification triggers:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger',
function (event, notification, state) {
  // Add some logic here:
  console.log("received: ", notification);
});
```

Check the [ngCordova docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/) for more events and information.